# Rails multiple radio buttons not independent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I am very new to rails.  As part of a form, I want a set of radio buttons for each member.

As a trial, part of my /view is:

```
     <table>
         <tr>
            <% Topic.listings.each do |listing| %>
               <td><%= listing %></td>
            <% end %>
          <tr>
          <tr>
             <% Topic.listings.each do |listing| %>
                <td>  <%= render 'layouts/button' %> </td>
             <% end %>
          </tr>
     </table>
```

layouts/_button.html.erb is:

```
    <%= radio_button_tag(:listing, "present") %>
    <%= label_tag(:listing_present, "Present") %><br>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:listing, "absent") %>
    <%= label_tag(:listing_absent, "Absent") %><br>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:listing, "unknown") %>
    <%= label_tag(:listing_unknown, "Unknown") %><br>
```

and in the /model:

```
   def self.listings
      @listings = ["A","B","C"]
   end
```

This gives me a set of 3 radio buttons under each member of the listing as desired but the radio button groups are not independent. If a button is selected under "A" then clicking a button under "B" or "C" removes it.

Please, how can I get the groups of buttons to be independent. Thank you.

HowardG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the HTML generated. [Radio buttons are grouped by name](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio).

The radio buttons you geenerate have the same name attribute (listing). That's why they are grouped together.

Each group should have a different name for the three buttonsand then it will work.

```
 <% Topic.listings.each do |listing| %>
   <td>  <%= render 'layouts/button', listing: listing %> </td>
 <% end %>
```

and

```
<%= radio_button_tag("listing_#{listing.id}", "present") %>
<%= label_tag("listing_#{listing.id}_present", "Present") %><br>
<%= radio_button_tag("listing_#{listing.id}", "absent") %>
<%= label_tag("listing_#{listing.id}_absent", "Absent") %><br>
<%= radio_button_tag("listing_#{listing.id}", "unknown") %>
<%= label_tag("listing_#{listing.id}_unknown", "Unknown") %><br>
```

Comment: Many thanks coorasse that worked fine after I removed all the 'id's ('id' was not defined in my code).  Would it have been more professional to have created an 'id' method?

Comment: I would have expected it to be present, maybe you can use a name or another attribute. Please upvote and approve the answer if is correct.